# error while loading json? key must be string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

trying to read my json data but it shows this error while using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_json(r"1_lines.json")
print(data)
```

error

```
ValueError: Key name of object must be 'string' when decoding 'object'
```

my_json

```
{1: [((86, 27, 169, 50), 'PSEG'), ((323, 33, 408, 41), 'Total amount due'), ((499, 26, 591, 44), '$26,930.17'), ((85, 53, 195, 63), 'We make things work for you.')], 
2: [((427, 24, 560, 31), ' LLC'), ((422, 35, 560, 42), 'Your account number: 4246'), ((454, 44, 560, 50), 'Invoice Number: 60438'), ((53, 82, 170, 93), 't Metering Program')]}
```

when using other code

```
import json
json_data= open("1_lines.json").read()
json_obj=json.loads(json_data)
print(json_obj)
```

error

````
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)```
````

Comment: Because your JSON format is wrong . Please validate your json in following website https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com. Also json key must be sting .

Comment: Use double quotes in every string values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your my_json is dictionaty and not json. T0 convert json from dictionary

```
import json
a=json.dumps(my_json)
```